# Grails many-to-one expose id without lazy load?

Tags: grails, associations, lazy-evaluation, many-to-one

Grails - How can I expose the id of a many-to-one association property without forcing a load of the entire object?

```
class Task {
  User belongsTo
  User createdBy
}
class User {
  ...
}
```

Can I get get the User ids from Task without causing lazy loading of the entire User objects?  Is there a way to do this in general, or will it involve a custom query for each class?  This actually involves DTO objects to return via BlazeDS - all I need are the ids, not the associated objects necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Grails by default has lazy association enabled so you don't have to worry about the loading of all chained objects unless you enable eager fetching. further more you could use named queries or hibernate criteria projections:
e.g.

```
 def taskCriteria = Task.createCriteria()  
 def users = taskCriteria.list{//or get
     projections {
         property "id"
     } 
     user{
         eq("userName", "Joe")
     }   
 }
```

the above will pull only the id of a task for a user called Joe.

Comment: What I would like to do is to map a domain object into a dto, with an id in place of the associated class object (in some cases).  I want to rely on hibernate to fetch the initial domain object.  I can put the User child class id into the dto by just referencing "createdBy.id", for instance.  However, this causes a fetch of the entire User object, and I just want the id.  I know the lazy loading proxy has access to the id, obviously, because that's the key to the fetch.  I would like to access that id without causing a fetch.

Comment: i see what you mean, there is a DTO plugin for grails that im sure you looked at. have you considered named queries? you could use it along projections:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html
other than that you would have to reference to hibernate documentation for that matter:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to use the magic notation belongsToId and createdById - see [GRAILS-2570](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2570)